# Learning and applying algorithms for applications

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Hi, I have been trying to learn algorithms for sometime with very little luck. I have tried adopting a couple of books on the subject area like:

- Algorithms by R. Sedgewick
- The art of programming by Knuth
- Intro to Algorithms by Cormen

I would really appreciate if someone can suggest me absolutely essential beginner's book on algorithms that can help me understand the above books and its materials better. Thanks for suggestions in advance

Comment: Sedgewick's book is more difficult... you can try to follow the alg classes by Stanford in Coursera. they are reasonably easy for entrance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop reading. Start Jumping-in, and try to make something with real-world application. You will learn 5-fold faster :)

You will face many real-challenges and questions; which many in StackOverflow will be very happy to help you with :) Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above books i would highly recommend [MIT's video lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/).

[Algorithms in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201756080) is also worth looking at.